# How to pass a parameter to a class constructor called by yaml.load_all

Tags: python, parsing, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file describing my objects and

```
--- !MyData
name: theName
param: parameter
data_file: \\path\to\my\file.csv
```

My code is the following

```
class Load(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name="",
             param = param,
             useDataFile=False,
             data_file = "none",
             **kwargs):

        super().__init__(name=name,
                     data_file = data_file)

def load_constructor(loader, node):
    values = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)  
    return Load(**values)

yaml.add_constructor(u'!Load', load_constructor)
```

At init time the main uses this to load the data

```
 with open(self.initFile, 'r', newline='') as ymlfile:
     for item in yaml.load_all(ymlfile):
         if type(item) is Load:
              ---- some post init code
```

Everything works fine but since my main code already knows the full path of *data_file* since it is in the same directory than the yaml,
is there a way to only give the name of the *data_file* without full path so that I can change the location without editing yaml config file? Since the *data_file* is loaded by the Parent class called through the *yaml.load_all* function I don't know how to give a parameter telling the path value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different solutions for getting a variable `path` dynamically in the Load instance, including:

- You can create a Load factory object, and set `path` on factory in the `load_constructor` call the factory instead of `Load` directly.
- You can make the load_constructor into an instance of a class, set `path` on that instance and have its `__call__` method do the construction

The latter you could do with:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
--- !MyData
name: theName
param: parameter
data_file: file.csv
"""

class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name, data_file, path=None):
        self._name = name
        self._data_file = (path + data_file) if path is not None else data_file

class Load(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name="",
             param = "param",
             useDataFile=False,
             data_file = "none",
             path=None,
             **kwargs):

        super().__init__(name=name,
                         data_file = data_file, path=path)

class LoadConstructor:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self._path = None

    def set_path(self, path):
        self._path = path

    def __call__(self, loader, node):
        values = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
        values['path'] = self._path
        return Load(**values)

load_constructor = LoadConstructor()
yaml.add_constructor(u'!MyData', load_constructor)

# using the above:
# set the default path
load_constructor.set_path('/my/path/to/csv/')
# parse YAML documents
for item in yaml.load_all(yaml_str):
    if type(item) is Load:
        print('data file:', item._data_file)
```

Please note that I had to change the first argument of the constructor otherwise a YAML object of type `MyData` could not be constructed. Also `param` needs to be defined if you use it as value for `Load.__init__()` (as key is of course fine), so I quoted that.

Running the above (under Python3) will give you:

```
data file: /my/path/to/csv/file.csv
```